# Redirect anonymous users to the register page

Tags: 6, users, redirection

Is it possible to redirect anonymous user to user/register page?
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module and setup a rules that redirects anonumoys users to the user/register page.